# Which will have Negative Implications on Application

Tags: asp.net

Need your inputs here , which one will have Negative Implications on Application

Accessing a key from web.Config or Accessing a key from Application Object .

Comment: Can you please clarify your question a bit? Which negative implications do you want to avoid? what is the goal you want to accomplish?

Comment: @Markus Performance wise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based upon the comment, the main factor is performance. Of course, accessing the key in the Application object will be slightly faster as the data is available in memory. However, I don't think that this performance difference will make or break your application. One should avoid premature optimization.

So I'd suggest to create a central class that provides the value. You can first retrieve the value from the web.config; if you later recognize that this is does not perform well enough, you can change the inner implementation of the class without influencing all spots in the code where you use the setting.

Comment: ok Thank you Markus , I will try that , What I draw from your answer is , we will not have much performance Improvement.